# How many languages over {0, 1} are there that contain only strings of length n?

Tags: formal-languages

For example, if n = 1, then there are 4 languages: ∅, {0}, {1}, and {0, 1}.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Why should a language be non-empty?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Every element of the empty set has length $n$, so the empty set contains only strings of length $n$. Properly interpreting quantifiers over the empty set is not just a matter of taste!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I agree, every element of the empty set has length $0$. But it's also true that every element of the empty set has length $42$, and every element of the empty set is miniature giant space hamster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2^n$ strings of length $n$, so there are $2^{2^n}$ sets of strings of length $n$.